# Generating interesting random TMs

Tags: computer-science, computability

To get a more intuitive understanding of the halting problem I want to generate some random TMs and see how they behave, what some heuristics can tell about them, etc.

The problem is that, if I correctly recall a paper I once saw, the probability for random TMs, from some reasonable distribution, to quickly halt or enter a trivial infinite loop approaches 1 as the number of states grows. That makes for boring research.

I want to know if there is a distribution of TMs in which this is not true. That is, for most TMs, it's not obvious if they halt or not. Although I'm not particular about TMs - any model of computation will do.

Comment: I realize that I can just generate TMs from a natural distribution, run them for n steps and discard ones that halt or get stuck. It's just not very efficient...

Comment: Here is an idea. You can randomly generate primitive recursive functions $f$ taking one integer parameter and returning one integer between say, $0$ and $1000$. Then your Turing machine would be the search for some parameter $n$ such that $f(n)$ has certain properties. For example 'equal $0$', or 'different from $0$', or 'between $0$ and $10$', etc... You can probably vary a lot the halting probability this way. I'm not sure, however, how this can help to get a better understanding of the halting problem.

Comment: @Archimondain, I worry that this way the TMs will all be of a similar structure, not representative of the random case. But I'll have to try it. Consider turning your comment into an answer.

Comment: Have you heard of Chatin's $\Omega$ constant ? It is roughly the probability that a programs halt and this 'number' has a lot of interesting properties (from a theoretical point of view at least). If you like I can make a detailed answer about it, together with my comment, although, the Wikipedia article about it seems quite good.

Comment: @Archimondain, from what I just read, I don't see how Chatin's constant would help me here. Regardless, you should move the comments into an answer.